# ios - How does UITabBarController size its subviews? Helps creating secondary TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I implemented an extra `TabBar` up top using a customized `UITabBarController`.
The top `TabBar` slides down, displaying more options.

The problem is that it sits on top (blocking a portion) of the child views (i.e. Home, Search, etc.)

What I am after is something like a `TopLayOutGuide`, but I know that is for transparent bars. I'm not sure that is the right way to approach this. I can go into each individual view (Home, Search, etc) and change the view so it anchors itself on the bottom anchor of the top `TabBar`, but the top bar is moving and could cause problems. I set the height of the top `TabBar` as 60.

How does the `UITabBarController` know how to size its subviews (Home, Search, etc) so they are always above the `TabBar`? I would like to be able to do that with the top `TabBar` so the subviews are always below the `TabBar`. The images below show what I mean.

[image: TabBar Blocks View]

[image: Views from side]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to create a view container encapsulating the views. Not the solution I wanted, but a solution none-the-less.

Here's the code in case someone needs it.

Initializing the tabController

```
func application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
{
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    tabController = TabControls()

    self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Custom tab controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    //ADD TABS
    let tab1 = homeCtrl
    let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "homeIcon"), tag: 1)
    tab1.tabBarItem = icon1
    tab1.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5, 0, -0.5, 0)
    tab1.title = nil
    let tab2 = searchCtrl
    let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "tabSearch"), tag: 2)
    tab2.tabBarItem = icon2
    tab2.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0)
    tab2.title = nil
    let controllers = [tab1,tab2]
    self.viewControllers = controllers

}
```

Custom Controller Encapsulating the view I want minimized

```
class SearchViewContainer : UIViewController{
    var searchCtrl:SearchViewController!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        searchCtrl = SearchViewController()
        searchCtrl.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchCtrl.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(searchCtrl.view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchCtrl.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            searchCtrl.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            searchCtrl.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            searchCtrl.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: -60),
            ])
    }
}
```